# Problemas al enviar petición con header Authorization en Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

que puedo hacer para que pueda funcionar una petición con HttpClient desde Angular6, cuando uso jQuery.ajax todo funciona correctamente. pero con HttpClient me dice que no esta autenticado (Estoy usando autenticación con tokens JWT (funciona correctamente ..creo)).

**Mi servicio en Angular6

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.prod';
declare var $: any;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeService {

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

noFunciona() {
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJ...`
  })
};
this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/customer/home', httpOptions)
  .subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
   }, error => {
     console.log('Error', error);
  });
}

siFunciona() {
   const settings = {
     'url': 'http://localhost:5000/api/customer/home',
     'method': 'GET',
     'headers': {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJ...'
     }
   };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
 }


}
```

podrían ayudarme guiándome en que debo hacer para que pueda funcionar en la función noFunciona() ya que me manda el siguiente error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**LOG Devtools**

```
content-tss.js:2 content-tss.js loaded:  http://localhost:4200/#/home
VM7808:5 hosted page injected
content-ads.js:2 content-ads.js loaded:  http://localhost:4200/#/home
core.js:3123 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
VM7808:86 caught history
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/customer/home 401 (Unauthorized)
error.interceptor.ts:21 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://localhost:5000/api/customer/home", ok: false, …}error: nullheaders: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/api/customer/home: 401 Unauthorized"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 401statusText: "Unauthorized"url: "http://localhost:5000/api/customer/home"__proto__: HttpResponseBase
home.service.ts:28 Error Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/api/customer/home: 401 Unauthorized
```

mientras que en la función siFunciona() funciona correctamente y me trae los datos que necesito

** Network metodo siFunciona()
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 18 Sep 2018 14:43:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

** Network metodo noFunciona()
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 18 Sep 2018 14:28:00 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: El problema no es de CORS, es de autenticación

Comment: @PabloLozano sabes por que funciona la autenticación con ajax y no con HttpClient ?

Comment: Tendría que ver los detalles: mira la pestaña *Network* de la consola de Chrome y mira qué diferencias hay entre una llamada y otra. Aparentemente el header se añade igual en ambas, pero algo tiene que ser distinto para que en un caso llegue bien y en otro no

Comment: @PabloLozano ya agregue las imágenes de la pestaña _Network_ de la consola del navegador

Comment: @A.Monsalve te recomiendo que en lugar de las imágenes copies los status code como texto nomas, sino se hace más complicada de leer la pregunta y vas a tener menos posibilidades de que te respondan!

Comment: El problema no es CORS (como dijo @PabloLozano) y tampoco de net.core. El problema es la llamada. Por favor, arregla el titulo de la pregunta y los tags.

Comment: ya modifique el titulo y la pregunta, muchas gracias

Comment: disculpa como lo solucionaste o donde encontraste el interceptor?

Comment: @MartinBatunTec yo tenia creado un interceptor llamado JwtInterceptor el cual adicionaba al header la autorización
`Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.auth_token}`` 
el error era que le tenia los dos puntos y estaba de esta forma .
`Authorization: `Bearer: ${currentUser.auth_token}``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El código que has puesto me parece que no coincide al 100% con lo que realmente tienes:

En la llamada que te falla tienes lo siguiente:

```
'Authorization': Bearer: eyJhbGciOiJ...
```

Fíjate bien: te sobran los dos puntos (`:`) después de `Bearer`.

Curiosamente no tienes esos dos puntos en tu código, no sé de dónde salen pero debe ser la causa de tu problema.

Comment: si, mientras he trabajado ha cambiado por el tiempo de vida del token y lo he cambiado cuando caduca. por eso no concuerda en alguna de las imágenes y logs;
y en el codigo en el servicio no estan esos dos puntos, de donde crees que salen?

Comment: que vergüenza, fue un interceptor que tenia adicionando el header desde el. fue una estupidez mía. lo siento

Comment: Como se suele decir, *sh\*\* happens*

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que veo incorrecto es que definas un token fijo en el codigo, eso no seria correcto, deberias realizar una llamada al servicio de token como ser

```
http://localhost:5000/token
```

este deberias retornar el token que usen en la llamada al servicio y no uno fijo

Por otro lado veo que usaste comillas simples inclinadas ` para poner el Bearer en lugar de comilas simples ' cuando usas

```
'Authorization': `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJ...`
```

[ASP.NET Core Authentication with JWT and Angular – Part 1](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/)

revisa donde usa

```
[Route("api/auth")]
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpPost, Route("login")]
    public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)
    {
       //codigo

       var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
       return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
    }
```

esto retorna un token que es el que despues envias a la llamada de la api

Esto seria lo correcto y no poner un Bearer fijo

Comment: gracias por tus consejos, lo del token fijo era para hacer mas simple la exposición de mi problema. lo de los acentos graves ` es por que los uso para concatenar la variable que contiene el token del usuario logeado. 

    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.auth_token}`

y desde la API hago una correcta generacion del token. 
ya solucione mi problema y era por que un interceptor adicionaba el header a la petición y esta era la que contenía dos puntos Bearer : 

de verdad muchas gracias por tu comentario.